# Launching different storyboards from different apps using a menu

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard, deep-linking

This is for my final year project. I was a little ambitious and built 5 different xcode projects - non dependant on eachother. I am really stuck on finding a way to link all these applications together.

I was going to use deep linking; however the app needs to be on the app store, which i am not doing -as i say its a final year project.

I was thinking along the lines of using a menu system like below:

@IBAction func toggleMenu(_ sender: UIButton){

```
    if sender.currentImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"){
        menuOpen = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.copyButton.center = self.copyButtonCenter
            self.pasteButton.center = self.pasteButtonCenter
            self.cutButton.center = self.cutButtonCenter
            self.marketButton.center = self.marketButtonCenter
        }
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: .normal)

    }else{
        menuOpen = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.copyButton.center = self.menuButton.center
            self.pasteButton.center = self.menuButton.center
            self.cutButton.center = self.menuButton.center
            self.marketButton.center = self.menuButton.center
        }
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func closeMenu(_ sender: UIButton){
    if menuOpen{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.copyButton.center = self.menuButton.center
            self.pasteButton.center = self.menuButton.center
            self.cutButton.center = self.menuButton.center
            self.marketButton.center = self.menuButton.center
        }
        menuButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

}

Can someone help me on how to make these buttons launch the different applications?

Please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use custom URL schemes as outlined in detail here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html